# How to iterate multiple arraylist

Tags: java

In my application 2 Arraylists are there:

```
1) rejectedList  - employees info whose status is rejected
2) acceptedList  - employees info whose staus is accepted
```

those 2 Arraylists are added to one mainList and returned.

i need to iterate mainList , seperate those 2 lists and set to new 2 arraylists

```
    while(rs.next()) {

      UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();  
      // getting values from db

      userDTO.setUserKey(UserKey);
      userDTO.setGroupId(bankGroupId);
      userDTO.setDisplayUserId(displayUserId);
      userDTO.setStatus(status);

      if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("Reject")){
        rejectedList.add(UserDTO);
      } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Accept")) {
        acceptedList.add(UserDTO);
      }
    }

  mainList.add(rejectedList;
  mainList.add(acceptedList)
  return mainList;
```

Comment: What's your question? You want to re-create rejected and accepted list from the mainList? iterate through each item in mainList, then check for each item's getStatus() and add them to the right list.

Comment: mainList holds ( list1+ list2).   from mainList i need to separate that two lists and set them to new 2 lists

Answer (score -1):

So really you just want to sort the main list into two sections, based on the accepted/rejected attribute? If this is the case you may want to use a map.

Comment: yes. could u pls give any sample or any link source to do this

Comment: Finally i went on another way and completed. thanks for your efforts.